# How do I identify a tab if it is open and refresh with the new hyperlink in Vbscript?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, wsh

I have a script that opens a hyperlink with a variable to pull up the particular account on the intranet. However, if the "module" is open already (80% of the hyperlink is the same), I would like to just keep the same tab/window open and refresh it.

Right now my Vbscript merely uses the script host and opens in a new tab each time. Since the user may have multiple tabs open, I'm not sure how to indentify if they have the link I want open and then use that window to refresh the data.

```
Begin pseudocode Script Sub

dim LINK as string
dim variableHere as string
LINK = "link/section/comments.aspx/account=" & variableHere & "&SID=11111"
variableHere = APIAccountNumberAccessed

IF ("link/section/comments.aspx/account=" exists)
then open hyperlink in same tab: LINK
else open in new tab
End IF

End pseudocode Sub
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I've made some progress in identifying that one can use the Window.Open method to set the target name and open a link. However, I'm still getting an error.

Syntax

```
set varWindow = Window.Open "google.com", "targetName", "toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no"
```

This provides me with the error expected end of statement, error code 800A0401, right in the Window open line. Still can't get past this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an automatic feature if you reuse the targetName
so, you can use same destination and targetName to have one tab per url. like this:

```
Window.Open variableHere, variableHere, "toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no"
```

i don't remember if targetName accepts any strange character if not, you can replace

```
validName = variableHere
validName = replace(validName,"/","_")
validName = replace(validName,".","_")
validName = replace(validName,",","_")
'... and so on ...
Window.Open variableHere, validName, "toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no"
```

Comment: ERROR: "Expected End of statement", line/char match Window.Open

Comment: why don't you use javascript?